# Firebase Emulator Auth on Kubernetes pod not receiving request

Tags: firebase, kubernetes, firebase-tools, kind

I've deployed locally a k8s cluster with kind. The firebase emulator runs on a pod inside the cluster and has a ClusterIp Service assigned. When I'm sending a request to ***kind-firebase.yaml*** pod from the ***service.yaml*** pod, the request fails because connection cannot be established.

**the error**:

```
failed to establish a connection:
 Post \"http://firebase-service:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/demo-test
```

**CONFIGS:**

- ***firebase.json:***

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 4000
    }
  }
}
```

- ***kind-firebase.yaml:***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: firebase-system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: firebase-depl
  namespace: firebase-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: firebase-emulator
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: firebase-emulator
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: firebase-emulator
        image: fb-emulator
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1000m" # Up to 1 full core
          requests:
            cpu: "1000m" # Use 1 full core
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - name: auth
          containerPort: 9099
        - name: emulator-ui
          containerPort: 4000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: firebase-service
  namespace: firebase-system
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: firebase-emulator
  ports:
    - name: auth
      port: 9099
      targetPort: auth
    - name: emulator-ui
      port: 4000
      targetPort: emulator-ui
```

- ***service.yaml:***

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: auth-system
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
  namespace: auth-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      volumes:
      - name: google-cloud-key
        secret:
          secretName: firebase-sacc
      containers:
      # auth-api container configuration
          - name: auth-api
            image: auth-api-image
            volumeMounts:
             - name: google-cloud-key
               mountPath: /var/secrets/google
               readOnly: true
            ports:
            - name: auth-api
              containerPort: 3000
            - name: auth-api-debug
              containerPort: 8080
            readinessProbe: # readiness probes mark the service available to accept traffic.
              httpGet:
                path: /debug/readiness
                port: 8080
              initialDelaySeconds: 15
              periodSeconds: 15
              timeoutSeconds: 5
              successThreshold: 1
              failureThreshold: 2
            livenessProbe: # liveness probes mark the service alive or dead (to be restarted).
              httpGet:
                path: /debug/liveness
                port: 8080
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
              periodSeconds: 30
              timeoutSeconds: 5
              successThreshold: 1
              failureThreshold: 2
            env:
              - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.namespace
              - name: KUBERNETES_PODNAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: metadata.name
              - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_POD_IP
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: status.podIP
              - name: KUBERNETES_NODENAME
                valueFrom:
                  fieldRef:
                    fieldPath: spec.nodeName 
              - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
                value: /var/secrets/google/sacc.json
              - name: FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST 
                value: firebase-service:9099
              - name: GCLOUD_PROJECT
                value: demo-test
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-service
  namespace: auth-system
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
  - name: auth-api
    port: 3000
    targetPort: auth-api
  - name: auth-api-debug
    port: 8080
    targetPort: auth-api-debug
```

- in the file you'll see these env variables:

```
- name: FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST 
  value: firebase-service:9099
- name: GCLOUD_PROJECT
  value: demo-test
```

by using them, the firebase sdk used inside the app that represent ***service.yaml***, will set the sdk for using the firebase emulator and not the one in the cloud.

**Screenshots with the cluster:**

1. Here we can see the namespaces available.

- In the auth-system the ***service.yaml*** pod will be present.
- In the firebase-system the ***kind-firebase.yaml*** pod will be present.

[image]

2. ***service.yaml*** pod

[image]

3. ***kind-firebase.yaml*** pod

[image]

4. Here we can see the logs inside ***service.yaml*** pod when I send a request to the ***kind-firebase.yaml*** pod... the error:

```
failed to establish a connection:
 Post \"http://firebase-service:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/projects/demo-test
```

[image]

Thx for any help!

Comment: Hi Robert Mihai, your k8s yaml file is fine. So, check if your pods are running, how you are sending a request (service name, if the request is from another namespace), and check if all needed ports are configured for Firebase Emulator. Could you add some details to your question?

Comment: @IvanM. I've updated the question. The only way I made firebase emulator work from k8s cluster was by using hostNetwork:true for the pod. But I don't want to use it like this, I want to use ingress. The request will be like this: 
   Request -> ingress -> service pod -> firebase pod

Thx for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After connecting to the firebase pod and checking DNS Resolution, the service name must be:

```
firebase-service.firebase-system.svc.cluster.local:9099
```

So the env variable from ***kind-firebase.yaml*** must be:

```yaml
- name: FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST 
  value: firebase-service.firebase-system.svc.cluster.local:9099
```

Everything works fine now.